# ¿Cómo se instala PyQt5 en linux y que lo vea VSCode?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyqt5, vscode

He instalado Python 3.8.1 en Linux Lite y Visual Studio Code, y quiero seguir trabajando en un proyecto que usa PyQt5. Las demás librerías las levanta bien, pero con pyqt5 me da el error que no encuentra el módulo de nombre pyqt5.
Lo he instalado ya de 20 formas distintas, puedo entrar al Qt Designer y utilizarlo pero cuando quiero probar la aplicación no encuentra el módulo.
Cabe aclarar que soy nuevo en linux, y justamente por ésto es que quiero programar en linux y probar mis trabajos en ambas plataformas (windows y linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revisa si la version de python es la 3.8, a mi tambien me paso lo mismo y era porque lo estaba ejecutando con la version de python 3.9

Comment: El OP dice claramente que usa Python 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Si ingresas a la consola de comandos y pones el codigo: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` deberia de instalarse

Comment: Esa es una de tantas formas que probé. Lo tengo instalado muchas veces, pero cuando entro al VSCode no puedo programar ni tampoco puedo compilar un programa terminado, saltándome el error de que no existe el módulo